# List files while uploading in powershell

Tags: powershell, file, concurrency, upload, get-childitem

I want to list files in a folder while another file is uploading in this same folder. But when I submit the code, it waits until the upload finishes to execute the command. How can I list the files without waiting for another external actions?

```
$Path = "files\i\want\to\list\inside\the\folder"
$List = Get-ChildItem $Path
```

Comment: you will need to use some sort of parallelism. take a look at `Get-Help about_Jobs`, `Get-Help Start-Process`, and the PoshRSJob module for various ways to  do that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I would do:

```
    Start-Job -Name "getList" -Scriptblock { $Path="files\i\want\to\list\inside\the\folder"; $pathList = Get-ChildItem $Path}
    $List = Receive-Job -Name "getList"
```

Here is what it would do:

1. Create a Job running in the Background collecting the directory contents
2. Receive the contents of the Job and put them into variable $List

Of course, you might want to make this an internally looping Job, so it will keep collecting and replacing the data. To stop it, you would use `Stop-Job -name "getList"`.

With this, you can run the copy command and receive the directory data after that. Please keep in mind that huge directory trees will slow down the job and therefore the data refresh rate.